# How can i send the message from client to server using signalr with proxy?

Tags: jquery, proxy, server, client, signalr

I  am  new to signalr. I  am created a hubproxy in client without autogenerated proxy. how can i send  messages  from my javascript proxy to server?

**Done:-**

Signalr  receive instant  messages  from server hub class successfully.

**ToDo:-**

**I need to send  ConnectionId  from client to  server hub class via  hubproxy in Client  and Respond the  requested client  based on the connectionId through  hub class in Service**

I  don't  know,how to send the data  from client to server with hubproxy?

Javascript Client:-

```
_signalr:function(){
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var proxy=this;
        var service = $.connection.serviceHub;
        var ServiceHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('serviceHub');
        ServiceHubProxy.on('addMessage', function signalr(widgetName,info) {
            if (widgetName == "Layout")
                proxy._renderDashboardLayout(null, info);
            else
                proxy._renderControl(null,widgetName, info);

        });
        connection.url = 'http://localhost:58087/signalr';
        connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
            var Id = connection.id;
            console.log(Id);
            console.log("Connected");
             proxy.loadLayout();
        });
},
```

HubClass:-

```
[HubName("serviceHub")]
public class ServiceHub : Hub
{
   public void Send(string widgetName,object info)
   {
    var service = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServiceHub>();
    service.Clients.All.addMessage(widgetName,info);
    }
}
```

Owin Startup Class:-

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var configuration = new HubConfiguration();
        configuration.EnableJSONP = true;

        app.MapSignalR(configuration);
    }
}
```

Could anyone,provide a  solution?

It  will  be  more  helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function in Back End to receive a call from client-side.

```
[HubName("serviceHub")]
public class ServiceHub : Hub
{
   //send to client
   public void Send(string widgetName,object info) 
   {
        var service = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServiceHub>();
        service.Clients.All.addMessage(widgetName,info);
    }
   //receive from client
   public void ReceiveAnAjaxFromClient(string data) 
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```

On client-side you will send an ajax for ReceiveAnAjaxFromClient

Comment: thank you Marlon.i have one doubt!  why  we  won't able  to  send  data  from client  to server with  proxy?  Using  ajax is  possible  i knew  that.but  with signalr  javascript  proxy?